# Android usb debugging not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an app and also wanted to check cross compatibility.
I've checked it in Nexus 5 and the app is working fine.
Now after installing the same app in Micromax A78(2.3-android version), when i open the app i see an exception saying app closed unexpectedly.

Actual problem goes here, **i've enabled USB debugging in Micromax but when i connect to my PC(Windows XP2)... no logs are shown in logcat...**
Could someone please help me how to get out of this issue...

Comment: maybe proper android driver is not installed in your system.Check it and if not installed install it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't confirmed the RSA fingerprint popup? , Check USB Debugging, Connect to PC and choose Charge only, A popup supposed to show up, if you can't see it, try to go to Camera mode instead charge only.

Comment: As soon as i connected the usb cable three options has shown up... Charge only,turn on debug mode and turn on usb storage... I've clicked on 2nd option and a pop up came asking allow usb debug i clicked ok... But nothing turned up in log cat

Comment: No Idea on how to connect the device??